# Walk through the Toast module in React Native

Tags: android, facebook, react-native

I am very new to react native. I need to use a pure native SDK provided by external source in a React Native Application. This is the link I found(the toast example).

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html

I have gone through the documentation but I really don't get it. 
Can someone walk through the Toast module specifying what really needs to be written where in the default project structure of react native that is created using react-native init "ProjectName"?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. The solution is:

1. First `import ToastAndroid` to your project: `import {ToastAndroid} from 'react-native';`
2. Then you can use it in your project like this: `ToastAndroid.show('A pikachu appeared nearby !', ToastAndroid.SHORT);`

Or follow this link: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/toastandroid.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import {ToastAndroid} from "react-native"

    try {
       // your task
    } catch (e) {
        ToastAndroid.show('Could not add the book.', ToastAndroid.LONG)
        console.warn("Error", e);
    }
```